# Get count where relation (one-to-many) doesnt exists in same table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to get Number of records which dont have relations (one-to-many) but the problem is it is in the same table and i am not sure how to do this.

```
| id | person_id    | name       | 
+----+--------------+------------|        
|  1 | NULL         | John Doe   |
+----+--------------+------------|    
|  2 | NULL         | Jane Doe   |  
+----+--------------+------------+ 
|  3 | 1            | Junior J.D.|  
+----+--------------+------------+
|  4 | 1            | Senior J.D.|  
+----+--------------+------------+
```

Now from this, for example i would like to get `count = 1` since Jane Doe doesnt have a relationship (doesnt have one-to-many).

For better explanation i need (from example) people who are "Single", as "John Doe" has child "Junior J.D." so he doesnt count.

I know how to get count of people who dont have relation (using Laravel Raw)

```
 $query = DB::table('people')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
                 ->where('person_id', '=', NULL)
                 ->get();
```

For now i figured i would use Exists but i am not sure how to implement that (or i might be wrong).

Comment: Did you try `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`?

Comment: But that would return 2 as in example. I need count where Person doesnt have a relationship (Where he is single)

Comment: I don't understand why there should be only count 1? There is no other redundant data which could be used for grouping etc. like `person_id`. Or do you want to group by lastname?

Comment: @rbr94 i went with this approach since Children and Parents in my table have same fields, so i put one-to-many in same table. I didnt have any problems with getting data so far. But the problem that i stumbled was this one (how to get people who dont have children)

Comment: But it is not normalized database. See my edited answer.

Comment: @rbr94 Good thinking, but children can have different surnames (what if daugther got married, etc.). But i would need something to check if relation exists (if parent has children) if there are any and then count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `whereNull` method to get only rows that have column that have NULL value.

So,

**Edit**: After your edit, I think i understood the question.

This SQL query should work for you:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) as count
FROM people
WHERE person_id IS NULL
    AND id NOT IN (
         SELECT person_id 
         FROM people 
         WHERE person_id IS NOT NULL
    );
```

If we translate this to Laravel:

```
$query = DB::table('people')
             ->whereNull('person_id')
             ->whereIn('id', function($query) {
                 $query->select('person_id')
                       ->from('people')
                       ->whereNotNull('person_id');
             }, 'and', TRUE)
             ->count();
```

Third argument to `whereInSub` is for boolean logic to combine query. And fourth argument means we want `NOT IN`.

This is not tested. So please test it and let me know if it works.

Also this is not the best way to do it i guess. If its possible I suggest to change your database structure.

Comment: Or simpler:  $query = DB::table('people')->whereNull('person_id')->count();

Comment: But this would return all who don't have relations, but i need to return count of those who dont have relationships (are Single in my example)

Comment: @MePo, Aah, sorry. I understood the question wrong. I will edit my answer, if i find a solution for that.

Comment: @CanVural No worries, I explained it wrong (will also edit so people can understand better)

Comment: Will try it out

Comment: it Gives me syntax error, unexpected '}'. but i will try to figure out.

Comment: @MePo, yeah. A semicolon is missing after `whereNotNull` in sub-query.

Comment: Yeah found that. Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'in_sub' in 'where clause' it what gives now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125174/discussion-between-can-vural-and-mepo).

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
$query = DB::table('people')
        ->whereNull('person_id')
        ->groupBy('name')
        ->count();
```

Comment: As discussed with CanVural this will give me 2 person (see edit of my question). And i need only person (from example) who is "Single"

Comment: Now try.. Updated my answer

Comment: This will give me 2 (see Edited Question). What i want to achieve is to get People who dont have children. Now from example John Doe has 2 of them. while Jane Doe has none. So result i would like to achieve is 1 (count of single people). And excuse me for my bad explanations.

Comment: @Komal Grouping by name won't help because the firstname is also in the same field as lastname. I think he needs to seperate both lastname and firstname.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `whereNull` instead of `where('person_id', '=', NULL)`. Furthermore split the `name` column to `firstname` and `lastname` columns, then you can do the following:

```
$query = DB::table('people')
    ->whereNull('person_id')
    ->groupBy('lastname')
    ->count();
```